# How did I win this Tic-Tac-Toe?

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking

[This is a normal tic-tac-toe with similar rules, 3 in a row to win.]

Who WON?

[image: Here's the game]

Comment: Please let me know what are the down votes for? So i can prevent them in the future.

Comment: I didn't downvote myself, but erm... According to the story you would have written "WHO WON??" above the puzzle before your sister even walked into the room. (Which doesn't make as much sense as opposed to writing that before posting it to PSE)

Comment: It was already on the page we played.

Comment: I can't imagine a page with an empty tic-tac-toe grid with "Who won?" above it.

Comment: Maybe I should edit the question then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It looks like you have three O's in a row because of the title.

Answer (score 0):

Was:

> your sister using non-euclidean geometry to claim O's win? although with the same logic so does X!